# openssl in C, hash multiple times

Tags: c, hash, openssl

```
int main()
{
 SHA256_CTX context;
 unsigned char md[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
 char *input = NULL;
 printf("What to hash: ");
 scanf("%m[^\n]%*c", &input);
 size_t length = strlen((const char*)input);
 int i, n=0;
 SHA256_Init(&context);
 SHA256_Update(&context, (unsigned char*)input, length);
 SHA256_Final(md, &context);
 goto NORMAL;
 MORE:
 n++;
 SHA256_Update(&context, md, sizeof(md));
 SHA256_Final(md, &context);
 NORMAL:
 for(i=0; i<SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
   printf("%02x", md[i]);
 }
 printf("\n");
 if(n==5){free(input);exit(0);}
 goto MORE;
 return 0;
}
```

Why this *spaghetti code* doesn't correctly generate multiple hash (sha256)?

My output:

```
What to hash: paolo
254835d73cc88095a30fc74133beabe9d8463b2954493227b205ea326c8a9c86
f8c9fd41c9aea21015b375af8e30c55df62a74e750f6381c704579b326bff2cd
dbbae564faab81da846c904659e993542fbb20643f7e2f57cc62934dade3ed87
a07424dbf030c30b76eb6db0f32a4ed4af084b4d1523cc2cacefbd19a3d0525d
33041103d21220c8906a3cc0b6369ab38428a440aceb1c5cac963ec471ec1aac
d529745ec47c77aea87d6a5f63ea509223cbd756d77326f232b0cd1d14681e24
```

expected output (thanks to an online sha256 calculator):

```
string: paolo
254835d73cc88095a30fc74133beabe9d8463b2954493227b205ea326c8a9c86
afbdc26d1e74bf1e9f68f154883e0bf5a1b9878c5c631e78126b07fa21b79ecd
739efedfc55930ef8cb0d9df487a50ab5b06b7f66594e82e437723df1e6184a1
008f3e3942bfb4289ad8fbbd081e981c4e32ec6508d43d8c3ae10d1b42e792d0
5ec489fc8b5345f43d821b8bac6851d61dc5f4f1fb825a5b74cc18e7bbc3e1b3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're re-hashing the *binary* (byte) representation of the resulting hash, and not its hexadecimal representation. You have to convert it to hexadecimal (probably using `sprintf()` or alike) after every iteration.

As David Schwartz correctly pointed it out, you also have to re-`Init()` the hash context in order to clear it and not leave other erroneous data in it.

Comment: i've added `for(i=0; i<SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){ sprintf((char *)md+(i*2), "%02x", md[i]);}` but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @polslinux of course it doesn't. Your md buffer is not big enough - in fact, it could have easily crashed.

Answer (score 3):

When you start the second and subsequent hashes, you leave the `SHA256_CTX` full of leftover junk from previous loops. You need to call `SHA256_Init` again to reset it.

Comment: Well, I doubt. He's rather rehashing the binary (as opposed to textual) representation of the result of the previous iteration.

Comment: @polslinux: Because you have another bug. See H2CO3's answer.